# Can I add a git repository to my bower.json?

Tags: javascript, bower

I am trying to use bower to pull down a git repository when I run a `bower install`.  Is there any way of listing a git repository as a dependency?  I can't find any info in the documentation, but maybe I am looking in the wrong place.