# bower-download the github-forked version, how do I commit modification to the forked repo?

Tags: git, github, fork, bower

There is a small library that I want to fork and modify and use in my project. (the modification will occur as I develop the project)

Since I use bower to manage javascript libraries, I'd like to use bower for the forked library as well.

If I make a modification to the library, how do I commit the modification to the forked github repository as well?

Comment: You can just specify the git url in your `bower.json`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196707/can-i-add-a-git-repository-to-my-bower-json

Comment: yes I know I can download github-hosted libraries using bower, The question is, how should I modify and commit it to the repository? Can I modify the bower-downloaded code and commit it? if so how?

Comment: Yes, bower looks at the git tags in the repository. If you tag a commit as a higher semver as the latest, bower will pick that up.

Comment: How do I commit my modification back to the forked-github-repository? My original question's wording was confusing, and I edited it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you're asking how to *modify the copy in `bower_components`* and then commit that back?

You can use `bower link` for that. First, clone your fork of the library:

```
git clone https://github.com/eugene/libfoo
```

Then, tell bower you have a local repository of libfoo:

```
cd libfoo
bower link
```

Finally, install a symlink to the library into your project:

```
cd myproject
bower link libfoo
```

If you inspect the `bower_components` directory, you will find that `libfoo` is a symlink to the cloned repo for `libfoo`, which you can commit and push as you like.